# g++ compile error basic object construction

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, header-files

I'm receiving the error:

```
thing.cpp:5:1: error: ‘SquareThing’ does not name a type
 SquareThing::SquareThing()
 ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
make: *** [thing.o] Error 1
```

my thing.h file:

```
#define THING_H_
#ifndef THING_H_
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class SquareThing{

public:
        SquareThing();
        //other functions
private:
    int something;
    //more members

};
#endif
```

Any my thing.cpp:

```
#include "thing.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
SquareThing::SquareThing()
{
     something = 3;
}
//more functions below
```

This seems too rudimentary but I really can't seem to find the error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typically the header guard, `MAZE_H_`, would reflect the name of the file, so as to avoid duplication. If any of your other files are also defining `MAZE_H_`, your entire `thing.h` header will be skipped...

Comment: my apologies, I made a fundamental error in placing 'MAZE_H_' instead of 'THING_H_'. My actual code has 'THING_H_' and still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two statements are backward:

```
#define THING_H_
#ifndef THING_H_
```

You most certainly meant:

```
#ifndef THING_H_
#define THING_H_
```

In the backward order, you were ensuring that the body of the header *never* kicked in, which isn't terribly useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the order of your macros:

```
#define THING_H_ // define the macro
#ifndef THING_H_ // if the macro is not defined (well, it is always defined...)
```

should be

```
#ifndef THING_H_ // if the macro hasn't been defined ...
#define THING_H_ // ... define it
```